# Trouble creating HttpResponse for xml download, Django

Tags: python, django, download, attachment

I'm trying to let the user download an xml file that i have generated.

This is my code:

```
tree.write('output.xml', encoding="utf-16")
# Pathout is the path to the output.xml
xmlFile = open(pathout, 'r')
myfile = FileWrapper(xmlFile.read())
response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='application/xml')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
return response
```

When I try to create my response I get this exception:

```
'\\'str\\' object has no attribute \\'read\\''
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Edit:
When I use this code I get no errors but instead the downloaded file is empty

```
tree.write('output.xml', encoding="utf-16")
xmlFile = open(pathout, 'r')
myfile = FileWrapper(xmlFile)

response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='application/xml')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
return response
```

Comment: I was wondering, do you really want to store the file? You could alternaively render it with a Django template.

Comment: @Wtower good question but wrong solution - you don't need a template to render the xml, just pass it (in string form) to the `HttpResponse` object.

Comment: The user have to be able to store the file, I don't need to store it on the server as long as it works :) @Wtower

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers what do you mean wrong solution? I have made a comment not an answer, for which your comment doesn't seem to answer it. In Django you don't have to use templates anyway, this doesn't mean that it is practical.

Comment: @Wtower what I mean is that using a Django template to render already well-formed XML is just useless when you can just pass the XML directly to the `HttpResponse` object.

Comment: "using a Django template to render already well-formed XML is just useless": true, but is this a pre-existing well-formed XML file or is this an XML file that is created only to be downloaded?

Comment: In this situation the file is created just to be downloaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `xmlFile.read()` - which yields a string - and passing the result to `FileWrapper()` which expects a readable file-like object. You should either just pass `xmlFile` to `FileWrapper`, or not use `FileWrapper` at all and pass the result of `xmlFile.read()` as your `HttpResponse` body.

Note that if you are creating the xml dynamically (which seems to be the case according to your snippet's first line), writing it to disk only to read it back a couple lines later is both a waste of time and resources and a potential cause of race conditions. You perhaps want to have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring

Comment: I get no errors when I do this and I can download the file. The problem is that it is now completely empty.

Comment: The elementtree tostring solved the problems for me :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the file and passing the resulting string to FileWrapper, instead of passing the actual file object.

```
myfile = FileWrapper(xmlFile)
```

Comment: Same thing here as above, no errors but the file is empty

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively from the other answers, I would recommend to completely go around the problem by utilizing the Django template system:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    t = loader.get_template('myapp/myfile.xml')
    c = Context({'foo': 'bar'})
    response = HttpResponse(t.render(c), content_type="application/xml")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=...'
    return response
```

In this way create a `myfile.xml` template which is used to render the proper xml response without having to deal with writing any files to the filesystem. This is cleaner and faster, given that *there is no other need to indeed create the xml and store it permanently*.

Comment: I managed to do this by using the `myfile = ElementTree.tostring() `command. And skip having to create the file locally this way.

Comment: Great, I am glad! I just thought to share my way too.

Comment: @Wtower: since the user is already creating the XML using `ElementTree` rewriting his code to use the template system would be a waste of time. Also `ElementTree` ensure you'll get well-formed XML, which is not the case with templates.

Comment: I haven't made the OP author or anyone to replace his code. I merely added another method and point of view. Things can happen in many ways and there are pros and cons either way.